# C# - Get RSA encryption progress

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, progress

How can I get RSA encryption progress? I want to display it in progress bar.
Thanks for help.

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography; 
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096);

//I want to get percentage process of this function, because it takes a lot of time.
byte[] encrypted = RSA.Encrypt(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("some text", true));
```

Comment: By keeping the total byte count in one variable, and the current byte count while encrypting in another. Read [ask], show your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: You can't, that method does not report progress. Your only option, if this is at all possible, is to call that method or a similar one with smaller chunks, updating progress in between.

Comment: **However**, you usually don't encrypt large binaries with RSA encryption. Instead you generate a random key and use a faster encryption method, like RIJNDAEL, only encrypting the key with RSA.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.

Comment: Substitute AES for RIJNDAEL. AES is a subset of Rijndael and Rijndael is not available on many platform while AES is. AES -> Advanced Encryption Standard. In some implementations AES is available as an option of Rijndael and many times the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a 16k-bit key I can do 1000 Encrypt calls in 2893ms (so ~3ms per), this doesn't seem slow enough to need a progress bar.

*Decrypt*, on the other hand, was 458,554ms for 1000 calls (so ~460ms per).  But half a second still doesn't really seem to warrant a progress bar.  And not very many people have 16k-bit RSA keys (since they take hours to generate)

Some other quick numbers (time per 1000 calls, in ms):

```
Keysize | Encrypt | Decrypt
--------|---------|--------
  16384 |    2893 | 458554
   4096 |     216 |  14636
   3584 |     182 |  13259
   3072 |     149 |   8370
   2560 |     127 |   4680
   2048 |      94 |   2083
   1536 |      86 |   1236
   1024 |      71 |    473
    512 |      64 |    150
```

So the best you could do is the fake progress bar of sending text messages... you do some heuristics for how long you think it will take, and artifically move the progress bar, then do an "eep" moment at 80% when it isn't actually done.

Since the guidance is to only use asymmetric operations to bootstrap symmetric operations (as already suggested in the comments), you can probably get away with using a progress bar on the symmetric operations only, if they're being slow enough for you to warrant it.  If you want to throw in a fudge factor for the asymmetric operation, it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Noting that the OP is using 4096-bit key the times are minuscule. There must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog post: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET

You can make each iteration of your for loop increase your progress bar.

For more specific help post your code and let us know where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using RSA.Encrypt function, and this is only one command. I want to get progress of this function, because it takes a lot of time.

Comment: I think you can be more specific there.. edit your question with some code so we can understand better what you do. What library do you use for RSA encrypt?

Comment: @Kaprog Is this specific library or from standard library? Tell the full path to class `System.Cryptographi...`.